# Hours calculation on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

the query below makes a count of the hours on the TotalOre field, the count must be **(OreFine-OreInizio) -Pausa** 
I count the total hours, I have loaded some example values ​​and the result is 23:30(TotaleOre)

**Input Value:**

```
OreFINE 
2017-07-26 16:30:00:000

Oreinizio
2017-07-26 17:30:00:000

Paura(Hour.Minute)
1.3
```

**Query:**

```
select  IdRisorseUmane,IdUtenteInserimento,u1.Nome+' '+u1.Cognome as InseritoDA,ExtraPreventivo,
    u2.Nome+' '+u2.Cognome as             Risorsa,
    RisorseUmane.IdUtente,IdCantiere,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Data, 105) as Data,
    Descrizione,
    convert(varchar(5), OreInizio, 108) as OreInizio,
    convert(varchar(5), OreFine, 108) as OreFine,
    REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as Pausa,
    convert(varchar(5),Cast(convert(varchar(5), (OreFine - OreInizio), 108) as datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as datetime), 108) as TotaleOre,
    TipologiaPreventivo.NomeTipologia as Tipologia   
from RisorseUmane  
    inner join Utente as u1  on u1.IdUtente = RisorseUmane.IdUtenteInserimento   
    inner join Utente as u2 on u2.IdUtente = RisorseUmane.IdUtente 
    inner join TipologiaPreventivo on TipologiaPreventivo.IdTipologiaPreventivo=RisorseUmane.IdTipologia
```

Comment: Without the table schema or sample data it's hard to understand what you want, or find a way to help. What's certain is that time calculations don't require conversions between text and dates. What's the purpose of `convert(varchar(5), OreFine, 108) as OreFine,REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':')` or `onvert(varchar(5),Cast(convert(varchar(5), (OreFine - OreInizio), 108) as datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as datetime), 108)`?

Comment: Simplify your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so  much easier to read - and to write!

Comment: To calculate differences between datetime values use `datediff`, not subtraction. `datediff(mi,StartDate,EndDate)` will return the number of minutes between two datetime values. Divide that by 60.0 to get fractional hours